# How to pass in variable to string with nested quotes - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this array of team names:

```
teams = ["Atlanta Hawks","Boston Celtics","Brooklyn Nets"]
```

I want to iterate over teams array, and insert each team into the css selector for 'title':

```
teams.each do |team_name|
    basketball_team_links << basketball_teams.css("a[class='lnkBeatWriterLeague'][title=#{team_name}]").map { |link| link['href'] }
end
```

Obviously my approach is flawed, and I can't figure out how to read in the |team_name| variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried with:

```
"a[class='lnkBeatWriterLeague'][title='#{team_name}']"
```

or:

```
"a[class='lnkBeatWriterLeague'][title=\"#{team_name}\"]"
```

or:

```
%Q{a[class='lnkBeatWriterLeague'][title="#{team_name}"]}
```

or:

```
"a[class='lnkBeatWriterLeague'][title='" + team_name + "']"
```

---

#### EDIT:

Adding a note on some corner cases that should be considered, as suggested by @Amadan in the comments.

Whether the `teams` strings come from a user or not, you might have apostrophes and quotes in them.
There are two simple ways to correctly escape them:

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.escapeHTML "input string"

require 'json'
"input string".to_json
```

Comment: Thank you, as I'm sure you are aware...they all worked.

Comment: Caveat: each of them will break under certain circumstances: `O'Reilly's Team`, `Sadist\"User`, `Jackie "Slugger" Jameson`. Escape your `team_name` using `CGI.escapeHTML`, use `team_name.to_json` to also get quotes (requiring `cgi` and `json`, respectively), or just `gsub` your string into submission to be on the safe side. "Psh, I'll never have apostrophes in my string" will bite you almost every time. :) (Of course, you should choose inner quotes to match the escaping method you employ)